# Nautilus does not connect via FTP after upgrade to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, ftp

Since I have upgraded to Oneiric, Nautilus is not able anymore to connect to FTP servers. When trying to connect it tells me I should use a different client. Original message in German:

```
Fehler: Fehler beim Verbinden: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt
Bitte wählen Sie einen anderen Betrachter und versuchen Sie es erneut.
```

Does anybody know what that means? Thanks for helping! I worked for a year using Nautilus for some simple FTP transactions...

[EDIT] The output of my /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache contents is (
I had to shorten it to be able to post it here):

```
     [MIME Cache]
application/asx=gnome-mplayer.desktop;
application/illustrator=inkscape.desktop;
application/java-archive=sun-java6-java.desktop;
application/mbox=evolution.desktop;
application/mdb=cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_msaccess.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_msaccess.desktop;
application/mime=opera-browser.desktop;
application/msaccess=cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_msaccess.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_msaccess.desktop;
application/msexcel=cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.ms-excel.desktop;libreoffice-calc.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.ms-excel::open.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_vnd.ms-excel::open.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_vnd.ms-excel.desktop;
application/mspowerpoint=cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_vnd.ms-powerpoint::open.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_vnd.ms-powerpoint.desktop;libreoffice-impress.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.ms-powerpoint::open.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.ms-powerpoint::show.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_vnd.ms-powerpoint::new.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_vnd.ms-powerpoint::show.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.ms-powerpoint::new.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.ms-powerpoint.desktop;
application/msword=cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_msword::open.desktop;libreoffice-writer.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_msword.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_msword.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_msword::open.desktop;
application/msword-template=cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_msword::open.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_msword.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_msword.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_msword::open.desktop;
application/musepack=gnome-mplayer.desktop;banshee.desktop;
application/mxf=totem.desktop;
application/ogg=foobnix.desktop;gnome-mplayer.desktop;guayadeque.desktop;clementine.desktop;audacity.desktop;soundconverter.desktop;totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;vlc.desktop;
application/pcx=phatch.desktop;phatch-inspector.desktop;
application/pdf=evince.desktop;gimp.desktop;pdfchain.desktop;inkscape.desktop;acroread.desktop;
application/pgp-encrypted=seahorse-pgp-encrypted.desktop;
application/pgp-keys=seahorse-pgp-keys.desktop;
application/pgp-signature=seahorse-pgp-signature.desktop;
application/postscript=evince.desktop;gimp.desktop;inkscape.desktop;
application/powerpoint=cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_vnd.ms-powerpoint::open.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_vnd.ms-powerpoint.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.ms-powerpoint::open.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.ms-powerpoint::show.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_vnd.ms-powerpoint::new.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_vnd.ms-powerpoint::show.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.ms-powerpoint::new.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.ms-powerpoint.desktop;
application/ram=totem.desktop;
application/rdf+xml=opera-browser.desktop;firefox.desktop;firefox-4.0.desktop;thunderbird.desktop;
application/rss+xml=opera-browser.desktop;firefox.desktop;firefox-4.0.desktop;banshee.desktop;thunderbird.desktop;
application/rtf=libreoffice-writer.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_msword.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_msword.desktop;
application/sdp=totem.desktop;
application/smil=gnome-mplayer.desktop;totem.desktop;
application/smil+xml=totem.desktop;
application/vnd.adobe.pdx=acroread.desktop;
application/vnd.adobe.xdp+xml=acroread.desktop;
[...]
application/vnd.ms-wpl=totem.desktop;
application/vnd.msaccess=cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_msaccess.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_msaccess.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database=libreoffice-base.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula=libreoffice-math.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics=libreoffice-draw.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics-template=libreoffice-draw.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation=evince.desktop;libreoffice-impress.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation-template=libreoffice-impress.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet-template=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-master=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-template=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-web=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/vnd.openofficeorg.extension=libreoffice-startcenter.desktop;
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation=libreoffice-impress.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation::show.desktop;
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slide=cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slide::show.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slide.desktop;
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow=cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow.desktop;
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template=libreoffice-impress.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template::show.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template::open.desktop;
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet=libreoffice-calc.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.desktop;
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template=cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template::open.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template.desktop;libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document=libreoffice-writer.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.desktop;
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template=libreoffice-writer.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template::open.desktop;
application/vnd.rn-realaudio=gnome-mplayer.desktop;
application/vnd.rn-realmedia=gnome-mplayer.desktop;totem.desktop;vlc.desktop;
application/vnd.scribus=scribus.desktop;
application/vnd.stardivision.calc=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/vnd.stardivision.chart=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/vnd.stardivision.draw=libreoffice-draw.desktop;
application/vnd.stardivision.impress=libreoffice-impress.desktop;
application/vnd.stardivision.math=libreoffice-math.desktop;
application/vnd.stardivision.writer=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/vnd.sun.xml.base=libreoffice-base.desktop;
application/vnd.wordperfect=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/vnd.xara=xaralx.desktop;
application/wordperfect=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/x-7z-compressed=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-7z-compressed-tar=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-ace=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-alz=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-anjuta=anjuta.desktop;
application/x-ape=gnome-mplayer.desktop;banshee.desktop;
application/x-ar=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-arj=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-audacity-project=audacity.desktop;
application/x-bittorrent=transmission-gtk.desktop;
application/x-brasero=brasero.desktop;
application/x-bzdvi=evince.desktop;
application/x-bzip=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-bzip-compressed-tar=file-roller.desktop;mount-archive.desktop;
application/x-bzip1=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-bzip1-compressed-tar=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-bzpdf=evince.desktop;
application/x-bzpostscript=evince.desktop;
application/x-cabinet=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-cb7=evince.desktop;
application/x-cbr=evince.desktop;file-roller.desktop;
application/x-cbt=evince.desktop;
application/x-cbz=evince.desktop;file-roller.desktop;
application/x-cd-image=brasero.desktop;file-roller.desktop;mount-archive.desktop;
application/x-cdrdao-toc=brasero.desktop;
application/x-chm=xchm.desktop;
application/x-compress=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-compressed-tar=file-roller.desktop;mount-archive.desktop;
application/x-cpio=file-roller.desktop;mount-archive.desktop;
application/x-cue=brasero.desktop;
application/x-dbf=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/x-deb=ubuntu-software-center.desktop;gdebi.desktop;file-roller.desktop;
application/x-debian-package=ubuntu-software-center.desktop;gdebi.desktop;
application/x-democracy=banshee.desktop;
application/x-doc=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/x-drm-v2=gnome-mplayer.desktop;
application/x-dvi=evince.desktop;
application/x-ear=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-extension-m4a=totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;
application/x-extension-mp4=totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;vlc.desktop;
application/x-extension-xar=xaralx.desktop;
application/x-flac=gnome-mplayer.desktop;guayadeque.desktop;soundconverter.desktop;totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;vlc.desktop;
application/x-flash-video=avidemux-gtk.desktop;totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;
application/x-font-bdf=fontforge.desktop;
application/x-font-otf=fontforge.desktop;gnome-font-viewer.desktop;
application/x-font-pcf=fontforge.desktop;gnome-font-viewer.desktop;
application/x-font-tex=fontforge.desktop;
application/x-font-ttf=fontforge.desktop;gnome-font-viewer.desktop;
application/x-font-type1=fontforge.desktop;gnome-font-viewer.desktop;
application/x-glade=glade-3.desktop;
application/x-gnome-saved-search=nautilus-folder-handler.desktop;
application/x-gnome-theme-package=gnome-theme-installer.desktop;
application/x-grsync-session=grsync.desktop;
application/x-gtar=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-gzdvi=evince.desktop;
application/x-gzip=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-gzpdf=evince.desktop;
application/x-gzpostscript=evince.desktop;file-roller.desktop;
application/x-id3=gnome-mplayer.desktop;banshee.desktop;
application/x-jar=sun-java6-java.desktop;
application/x-java-archive=sun-java6-java.desktop;file-roller.desktop;
application/x-java-jnlp-file=sun-java6-javaws.desktop;
application/x-lha=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-lhz=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-linguist=banshee.desktop;
application/x-lrzip=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-lrzip-compressed-tar=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-lzip=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-lzip-compressed-tar=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-lzma=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-lzma-compressed-tar=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-lzop=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-lzop-compressed-tar=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-matroska=totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;vlc.desktop;
application/x-mdb=cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_msaccess.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_msaccess.desktop;
application/x-mimearchive=opera-browser.desktop;
application/x-miro=banshee.desktop;
application/x-mmg-settings=mkvmergeGUI.desktop;
application/x-mplayer2=gnome-mplayer.desktop;
application/x-ms-dos-executable=wine.desktop;file-roller.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-0:application_x-crossover-exe::run.desktop;
application/x-ms-shortcut=wine.desktop;
application/x-ms-wmv=gnome-mplayer.desktop;
application/x-msaccess=cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_msaccess.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_msaccess.desktop;
application/x-msexcel=cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.ms-excel.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.ms-excel::open.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_vnd.ms-excel::open.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_vnd.ms-excel.desktop;
application/x-msi=wine.desktop;
application/x-mspowerpoint=cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_vnd.ms-powerpoint::open.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_vnd.ms-powerpoint.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.ms-powerpoint::open.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.ms-powerpoint::show.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_vnd.ms-powerpoint::new.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_vnd.ms-powerpoint::show.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.ms-powerpoint::new.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.ms-powerpoint.desktop;
application/x-msword=cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_msword.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_msword.desktop;
application/x-musepack=gnome-mplayer.desktop;banshee.desktop;
application/x-netshow-channel=totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;
application/x-nsv-vp3-mp3=gnome-mplayer.desktop;
application/x-ogg=foobnix.desktop;gnome-mplayer.desktop;clementine.desktop;soundconverter.desktop;totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;vlc.desktop;
application/x-ogm-audio=clementine.desktop;
application/x-onboard=onboard.desktop;
application/x-onboardsettings=onboard-settings.desktop;
application/x-opera-extension=opera-browser.desktop;
application/x-opera-uniteapplication=opera-browser.desktop;
application/x-opera-widgets=opera-widget-installer.desktop;
application/x-phatch=phatch.desktop;phatch-inspector.desktop;
application/x-qtconfig=qt3config.desktop;
application/x-quicktime-media-link=totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;
application/x-quicktimeplayer=gnome-mplayer.desktop;totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;
application/x-rar=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-rar-compressed=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-remote-connection=vinagre.desktop;
application/x-rpm=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-rzip=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-scantailor=scantailor.desktop;
application/x-shellscript=emacs23.desktop;
application/x-shockwave-flash=avidemux-gtk.desktop;vlc.desktop;
application/x-shorten=totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;
application/x-smil=totem.desktop;
application/x-sony-bbeb=lrfviewer.desktop;
application/x-stuffit=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-tar=file-roller.desktop;mount-archive.desktop;
application/x-tarz=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-toc=brasero.desktop;
application/x-troff-msvideo=banshee.desktop;
application/x-virtualbox-ova=virtualbox.desktop;
application/x-virtualbox-ovf=virtualbox.desktop;
application/x-virtualbox-vbox=virtualbox.desktop;
application/x-virtualbox-vbox-extpack=virtualbox.desktop;
application/x-vnc=vinagre-file.desktop;
application/x-vorbis+ogg=gnome-mplayer.desktop;
application/x-war=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-xz=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-xz-compressed-tar=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-zip=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-zip-compressed=file-roller.desktop;
application/x-zoo=file-roller.desktop;
application/xhtml+xml=opera-browser.desktop;firefox.desktop;firefox-4.0.desktop;thunderbird.desktop;
application/xhtml_xml=chromium-browser.desktop;
application/xml=opera-browser.desktop;firefox.desktop;firefox-4.0.desktop;thunderbird.desktop;
application/xspf+xml=totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;
application/zip=file-roller.desktop;mount-archive.desktop;
audio/3gpp=totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;
audio/AMR=totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;
audio/AMR-WB=totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;
audio/aac=clementine.desktop;
audio/ac3=totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;
audio/ape=gnome-mplayer.desktop;banshee.desktop;
audio/avi=banshee.desktop;
audio/basic=gnome-mplayer.desktop;audacity.desktop;totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;
audio/flac=gnome-mplayer.desktop;banshee.desktop;
audio/midi=gnome-mplayer.desktop;totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;
audio/mp=gnome-mplayer.desktop;banshee.desktop;
audio/mp2=banshee.desktop;
audio/mp3=gnome-mplayer.desktop;banshee.desktop;
audio/mp4=gnome-mplayer.desktop;guayadeque.desktop;clementine.desktop;totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;vlc.desktop;
audio/mp4a-latm=banshee.desktop;
audio/mpc=gnome-mplayer.desktop;banshee.desktop;
audio/mpeg=foobnix.desktop;gnome-mplayer.desktop;guayadeque.desktop;clementine.desktop;audacity.desktop;soundconverter.desktop;totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;vlc.desktop;
audio/mpeg2=gnome-mplayer.desktop;
audio/mpeg3=gnome-mplayer.desktop;banshee.desktop;
audio/mpegurl=guayadeque.desktop;clementine.desktop;totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;
audio/musepack=gnome-mplayer.desktop;banshee.desktop;
audio/ogg=gnome-mplayer.desktop;guayadeque.desktop;clementine.desktop;totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;
audio/prs.sid=totem.desktop;
audio/vnd.rn-realaudio=clementine.desktop;totem.desktop;vlc.desktop;
audio/vorbis=gnome-mplayer.desktop;clementine.desktop;banshee.desktop;
audio/wav=gnome-mplayer.desktop;banshee.desktop;
audio/wave=banshee.desktop;
audio/webm=gnome-mplayer.desktop;
audio/x-aiff=audacity.desktop;totem.desktop;
audio/x-amzxml=banshee.desktop;
audio/x-ape=gnome-mplayer.desktop;guayadeque.desktop;totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;
audio/x-basic=gnome-mplayer.desktop;
audio/x-flac=foobnix.desktop;gnome-mplayer.desktop;guayadeque.desktop;clementine.desktop;totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;vlc.desktop;
[...]
audio/x-realaudio=gnome-mplayer.desktop;totem.desktop;
audio/x-s3m=gnome-mplayer.desktop;banshee.desktop;
audio/x-sbc=totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;
audio/x-scpls=foobnix.desktop;gnome-mplayer.desktop;clementine.desktop;brasero.desktop;soundconverter.desktop;totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;vlc.desktop;
audio/x-speex=clementine.desktop;totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;
audio/x-tta=totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;
audio/x-vorbis=gnome-mplayer.desktop;clementine.desktop;totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;
audio/x-vorbis+ogg=foobnix.desktop;gnome-mplayer.desktop;clementine.desktop;totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;
audio/x-wav=gnome-mplayer.desktop;clementine.desktop;audacity.desktop;soundconverter.desktop;totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;vlc.desktop;
audio/x-wavpack=totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;
audio/x-webm=gnome-mplayer.desktop;
audio/x-xm=gnome-mplayer.desktop;totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;
image/*=evince.desktop;
image/avi=banshee.desktop;
image/bmp=phatch.desktop;gimp.desktop;phatch-inspector.desktop;eog.desktop;shutter.desktop;
image/g3fax=gimp.desktop;
image/gif=phatch.desktop;gimp.desktop;phatch-inspector.desktop;eog.desktop;shutter.desktop;firefox.desktop;firefox-4.0.desktop;
image/jpeg=shotwell-viewer.desktop;phatch.desktop;gimp.desktop;phatch-inspector.desktop;eog.desktop;shutter.desktop;firefox.desktop;firefox-4.0.desktop;
image/jpg=phatch.desktop;phatch-inspector.desktop;eog.desktop;
image/pcx=gimp.desktop;
image/pjpeg=eog.desktop;
image/png=shotwell-viewer.desktop;phatch.desktop;gimp.desktop;phatch-inspector.desktop;eog.desktop;shutter.desktop;firefox.desktop;firefox-4.0.desktop;
image/svg+xml=gimp.desktop;inkscape.desktop;eog.desktop;opera-browser.desktop;shutter.desktop;
image/svg+xml-compressed=inkscape.desktop;eog.desktop;
image/tiff=evince.desktop;shotwell-viewer.desktop;phatch.desktop;gimp.desktop;phatch-inspector.desktop;eog.desktop;shutter.desktop;
image/vnd.djvu=evince.desktop;djvulibre-djview4.desktop;
image/vnd.rn-realpix=totem.desktop;vlc.desktop;
image/vnd.wap.wbmp=eog.desktop;
[...]
image/x-wmf=gimp.desktop;
image/x-x3f=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-xbitmap=phatch.desktop;gimp.desktop;phatch-inspector.desktop;eog.desktop;
image/x-xcf=gimp.desktop;
image/x-xpixmap=phatch.desktop;gimp.desktop;phatch-inspector.desktop;eog.desktop;
image/x-xwindowdump=gimp.desktop;
image/x.djvu=djvulibre-djview4.desktop;
image/xpm=shutter.desktop;
inode/directory=nautilus-folder-handler.desktop;qgit.desktop;
message/rfc822=evolution.desktop;
misc/ultravox=totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;vlc.desktop;
text/calendar=evolution.desktop;
text/csv=cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.ms-excel.desktop;libreoffice-calc.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_vnd.ms-excel.desktop;
text/directory=evolution.desktop;
text/english=emacs23.desktop;
text/google-video-pointer=totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;
text/html=opera-browser.desktop;chromium-browser.desktop;firefox.desktop;firefox-4.0.desktop;thunderbird.desktop;
text/plain=emacs23.desktop;gedit.desktop;uex.desktop;
text/rtf=libreoffice-writer.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_msword.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_msword.desktop;
text/vnd.graphviz=cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_msword::open.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_msword.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_msword.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_msword::open.desktop;
text/vnd.wap.wml=opera-browser.desktop;
text/wml=opera-browser.desktop;
text/x-apport=apport-gtk-mime.desktop;
text/x-apt-sources-list=software-properties-gtk.desktop;
text/x-c=emacs23.desktop;
text/x-c++=emacs23.desktop;
text/x-c++hdr=emacs23.desktop;
text/x-c++src=emacs23.desktop;
text/x-chdr=emacs23.desktop;
text/x-comma-separated-values=cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.ms-excel.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_vnd.ms-excel.desktop;
text/x-csrc=emacs23.desktop;
text/x-csv=cxassoc-cxoffice-8c8c7dce-0ab7-462d-b68b-54f9e5fc6bc3:application_vnd.ms-excel.desktop;cxassoc-cxoffice-d5703819-3027-4eae-8127-ff0b5bc264a8:application_vnd.ms-excel.desktop;
text/x-google-video-pointer=totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;
text/x-java=emacs23.desktop;
text/x-makefile=emacs23.desktop;
text/x-moc=emacs23.desktop;
text/x-opml+xml=banshee.desktop;
text/x-pascal=emacs23.desktop;
text/x-tcl=emacs23.desktop;
text/x-tex=emacs23.desktop;texmakerx.desktop;texmaker.desktop;
text/x-vcard=evolution.desktop;
text/x-winswitchconfig=winswitch.desktop;
text/x-xptv=pitivi.desktop;
text/xml=opera-browser.desktop;chromium-browser.desktop;xmlcopyeditor.desktop;firefox.desktop;firefox-4.0.desktop;thunderbird.desktop;
video/3gpp=gnome-mplayer.desktop;totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;
video/avi=banshee.desktop;
video/dv=totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;vlc.desktop;
video/fli=gnome-mplayer.desktop;totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;
video/flv=avidemux-gtk.desktop;totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;
video/matroska=gnome-mplayer.desktop;
video/mp2t=gnome-mplayer.desktop;totem.desktop;
video/mp4=gnome-mplayer.desktop;totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;vlc.desktop;
video/mp4v-es=totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;vlc.desktop;
video/mpeg=me-tv.desktop;gnome-mplayer.desktop;avidemux-gtk.desktop;totem.desktop;banshee.desktop;vlc.desktop;
[...]
x-content/audio=foobnix.desktop;
x-content/audio-cdda=sound-juicer.desktop;brasero.desktop;banshee-audiocd.desktop;vlc.desktop;
x-content/audio-player=clementine.desktop;banshee-media-player.desktop;vlc.desktop;
x-content/blank-bd=brasero-nautilus.desktop;
x-content/blank-cd=brasero-nautilus.desktop;
x-content/blank-dvd=brasero-nautilus.desktop;
x-content/blank-hddvd=brasero-nautilus.desktop;
x-content/image-dcf=shotwell.desktop;
x-content/image-picturecd=brasero.desktop;
x-content/software=nautilus-autorun-software.desktop;
x-content/video-dvd=brasero.desktop;totem.desktop;vlc.desktop;
x-content/video-svcd=brasero.desktop;totem.desktop;vlc.desktop;
x-content/video-vcd=brasero.desktop;totem.desktop;vlc.desktop;
x-directory/gnome-default-handler=nautilus-folder-handler.desktop;
x-directory/normal=nautilus-folder-handler.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/apt=ubuntu-software-center.desktop;apturl.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/chrome=firefox.desktop;firefox-4.0.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/ftp=nautilus-folder-handler.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/ghelp=yelp.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/help=yelp.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/http=opera-browser.desktop;chromium-browser.desktop;firefox.desktop;firefox-4.0.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/https=opera-browser.desktop;chromium-browser.desktop;firefox.desktop;firefox-4.0.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/info=yelp.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/lastfm=banshee.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/magnet=transmission-gtk.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/mailto=evolution.desktop;opera-browser.desktop;thunderbird.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/man=yelp.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/u1ms=banshee.desktop;
```

Comment: The error, in English: "Error: Failed to connect: Connection refused
Please select another viewer and try again." *(Courtesy of Google Translate.)*

Comment: @user15533 can you please download [Lucid's gvfs-backends](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/gvfs-backends) and install it? (if needed remove the one you have).

Comment: Does that mean, that this is a known bug in Oneirics gvfs-backends?

Comment: there was from 10.10 to 11.04

Comment: But it worked for me till I updated to Oneiric. I tried to install Lucid's gvfs-backends, but it did not work and now I have a defect gvfs installation and no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Just run an update and an upgrade and it will fix it or `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gvfs-backends gvfs gvfs-bin`.

Comment: That does not work. I get following problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/80701/how-to-fix-broken-gvfs-package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could fix this issue by reinstalling the gvfs-backends package. I had some serious problems doing so, because apt-get was telling me, that my gvfs packages are broken not let me reinstall it (see here: [How to fix broken GVFS package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80701/how-to-fix-broken-gvfs-package)). So I purged it:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge gvfs-backends
```

Downloaded the package here http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/oneiric/amd64/gvfs-backends/download and installed it performing following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i gvfs-backends_1.10.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

After rebooting my machine I got it working again in spite of the fact that package manager is still telling me, that the package is broken.