# How to fix broken GVFS package?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, gvfs

Since I have upgraded to Oneiric I have some issues with the GVFS package. Because of the fact that nautilus is not able to handle FTP-Connections anymore, I tried to reinstall gvfs-backends as recommended in some posts. But apt-get isn't able to do so and I get the message:

```
Erneute Installation von gvfs-backends ist nicht möglich,
es kann nicht heruntergeladen werden.
```

Means something like: »New installation of gvfs-backends is not possible, can't be downloaded«
Trying to install it with GDebi I get following message:[image]

Anybody knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The error message suggest a network error or your package list is out of date.

First try

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

If that does not work, try another mirror close to your location.

Mirrors listed here : https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors